# Magento2.3: Where to check the controller output?

Tags: magento2.3, csv, export

I want to export the customer details as a CSV file. I have referred the below link for that:

https://magecomp.com/blog/export-data-csv-file-programmatically-magento-2/

I have put the code which is in the mentioned link to one of my custom module but where I have to check the controller output.

where the CSV file will be stored?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Check inside var folder

Comment: I can't see the CSV file inside var folder

Comment: Please check controller response in browser console.

Comment: Are you sure that your file generated successfully? And also you can give you custom folder path by editing
 $filePath = $this->directoryList->getPath(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR)
         . "/" . $fileName;
this line

Comment: @Nayem, I'm not sure whether the file is generated or not.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh, Ok

Comment: How can I confirm that whether the file has been generated or not since I can't see that in browser console as well?

Comment: Can you see your controller in the console? First, open the console file and then click on the export button. After that controller call and you can see it in the console. Then click on that controller file and check the response of that controller.